# FormView row count

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, formview

I have created an application which uses a `FormView` with `Select` and `Update` commands, the formview will only populate when I pass it a parameter, however here is where the problem is. If I pass the formview a parameter but in my database there is more than 1 row I want to be able to choose which row populates the formview using something like a dropdownlist as a formview only holds 1 row.

Comment: Question is not clear, i don't get what is you are asking for

Comment: @SujithKarivelil What don't you understand? In my database I have lots of records and when I pass my formview a recordID it should populate the formview, however some recordID's have multiple records within them, so I would like to choose which record should populate the FormView.

Answer (score 0):

Since there's no code, I'll answer with words as well:

Click on FormView control
Go to properties and set AllowPaging to true // Adding this property generates the paging interface automatically, which will display numbers for each record return from your database